# How to connect mqtt input node with HiveMQ

Tags: node-red

I'm following this tutorial: [enter link description here][1]

I drag and drop a MQTT input node and configure it. I set `Topic` and set `Server` and `Port`.

Then I go to the this link http://hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client And my host is like in mqtt input noode , and my port is like port in mqtt input node, my Topic is like Topic  in mqtt input node.

But my connection does not work.

I have connected the MQTT input node to a JSON and debug node.

Comment: You need to include a LOT more information for somebody to be able to help here. You seam to have missed the link out to start with. You connect to a HiveMQ broker the same way you would to any other.

Comment: I drag and drop an mqtt input node and configure it. I set  " Topic" and set "Server" and "Port". And I go to the this link http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/ 
And mu host is like in mqtt input noode , But is don't work

Comment: The explanation is ok now?

Comment: Not really, the link to the tutorial your following is still missing, you haven't mentioned of the green status marker is showing on the MQTT node to show off it's connected or if there is any information in the node-red logs. Including a screenshot of the MQTT "server" config screen from node-red would probably be useful as well

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanna start only clients(first on Node-RED and the second on with WebSocket-client).

To work with the MQTT, you need to start at the first server by yourself, or you can try to setup server address is broker.mqttdashboard.com . On the Node-Red post is 1883, but on HiveMQ client he is 8000.

And then everything should work.

I hope that I understood your problem.